# Background image for Listtile/card in gridview Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a widget tree as Gridview>Container>Card>ListTile but instead of having a leading image on the ListTile I want this as the background image of the card, is there a way to achieve this look?

Answer (score 4):

If i understand your question correctly, you can put that image in a Container:

```
Card(
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          fit: BoxFit.cover,  //I assumed you want to occupy the entire space of the card
          image: AssetImage(
            'the_path_of_the_image',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Text(
          'Testing the ListTile',
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        title: Text(
          'Testing again!',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
     ),
   ),
);
```